# R read from file different-sized arrays

Tags: file, list, r, size

I need to apply the Mann Kendall trend test in R to a big number (about 1 million) of different-sized time series. I've already created a script that takes the time-series (practically a list of numbers) from all the files in a certain directory and then outputs the results to a .txt file.

The problem is that I have about 1 million of time-series so creating 1 million of file isn't exactly nice. So I thought that putting all the time-series in only one .txt file (separated by some symbol like "#" for example) could be more manageable. So I have a file like this:

```
1
2
4
5
4
#
2
13
34
#
...
```

I'm wondering, is it possible to extract such series (between two "#") in R and then apply the analysis?

EDIT

Following @acesnap hints I'm using this code:

```
library(Kendall)
a=read.table("to_r.txt")
numData=1017135

for (i in 1:numData){

s1=subset(a,a$V1==i)
m=MannKendall(s1$V2)
cat(m[[1]],"  ",m[[2]], "  ", m[[3]],"  ",m[[4]],"  ", m[[5]], "\n" ,   file="monotonic_trend_checking.txt",append=TRUE)
}
```

This approach works but the problem is that it is taking ages for computation. Can you suggest a faster approach?

Comment: If you have a new question, the best thing to do would be to repost a new question. Especially as there is already an accepted answer.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I'll follow your hint

Comment: Whether or not this can be sped up depends on what the bottle neck is. If it is the looping, you could take a look at data.table from the data.table package. If it is the MannKendall test, then speeding this up can be a bit harder.

Comment: You can time the different parts of the loop using: 

# Start the clock!
ptm <- proc.time()
# Stop the clock
proc.time() - ptm

Just put them around the code you want to time and you'll see where the delay is coming from.  It's easier to adjust knowing where the slow part is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to number the datasets as they went into the larger file it would make things easier.  If you were to do that you could use a for loop and subsetting.

```
setNum        data
  1            1
  1            2
  1            4
  1            5
  1            4
  2            2
  2           13
  2           34
 ...          ...
```

Then do something like:

```
answers1 <- c()  
numOfDataSets <- 1000000
for(i in 1:numOfDataSets){
  ss1 <- subset(bigData, bigData$setNum == i) ## creates subset of each data set
  ans1 <- mannKendallTrendTest(ss1$data)      ## gets answer from test
  answers1 <- c(answers1, ans1)               ## inserts answer into vector
  print(paste(i, " | ", ans1, "",sep="" ))    ## prints which data set is in use
  flush.console()                             ## prints to console now instead of waiting
}
```

Comment: I've followed your hints and I'm using the code I posted up. The problem is that it is too slow. Can you suggest something else?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perhaps a more elegant solution:

```
# Read in your data
x=c('1','2','3','4','5','#','4','5','5','6','#','3','6','23','#')
# Build a list of indices where you want to split by:
ind=c(0,which(x=='#'))
# Use those indices split the vector into a list
lapply(seq(length(ind)-1),function (y) as.numeric(x[(ind[y]+1):(ind[y+1]-1)]))
```

Note that for this code to work, you must have a '#' character at the very end of the file.